# how to load a huge image on the style of google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps-styling

i would load a huge image in my web page (8Mpx x 5Mpx). I thought of creating a simple mechanism  on the style of google maps.. 
But, honestly, I do not have very clear ideas on how to implement it.. any advice on how to structure it?

in particular, I have many doubts about how to handle the drag with the asynchronous loading of the image to vary the portion of the images displayed

Thank you in advance for your help : )

Comment: Google stores their map images as MANY smaller tiles and loads each of the tiles on-demand. They also store the tiles at MANY different levels of zoom to prevent excessive zoom-jagginess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy answer would to be use Google Maps.

It's a rather advanced topic, but it shouldn't be any harder than doing it by hand.

Here is [more information](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Custom_Map_Types)

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of some sort of tiles. You break down the image in several parts ( tiles ).  Then you only draw the one that are in your viewport.

Comment: I also thought this, but the question is how to handle it:)

Answer (score 0):

I've used Zoomify's products in the past to accomplish this. I work on a team that manages a few datacenters, so we have some gigantic floor maps (drawn up in CAD, exported as a huge image). I take those maps and convert them to what I consider a "Google style map" using Zoomify Express (free).

More info here: http://www.zoomify.com/express.htm

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I'd like to suggest http://leafletjs.com/.